# non breaking space preceding katex not workiing in HTML

Tags: html, typography, katex

if I put a non breaking space before a katex inline formula like

```
<p>the quantity is represented by the variable&nbsp;$x$.</p>
```

It's good practice to avoid an orphan `$x$.` at the beginning of a line. However The non-breaking space`&nbsp;` has no effect here. The problem also occurs with the final point of the sentence.

I am expecting `variable&nbsp;$x$.` to be unbreakable. It doesn't works in firefox or chrome.

Comment: _"I am expecting `variable&nbsp;$x$.` to be unbreakable."_ - which it more or less _is_. But since you are using KaTeX, that is likely not the actual HTML you have there any more - KaTeX will have inserted its own elements into this, that wrap certain characters. The live demo on the library's page shows, that many of those spans will get `display: inline-block;` applied - and that's when non-breaking spaces stop working. https://jsfiddle.net/d802zgnx/